# How to disable/restrict browser reload/refresh functionality?

Tags: javascript, reload

Trying to do this, which is executing a default behaviour.

```
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeUnloadFunc);

   function beforeUnloadFunc(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = '';
      return null;         
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this!

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    if(event.keyCode == 116) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            return false;
           }
}
```

Source
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/243851/How-to-disable-back-forward-and-Refresh-functional